# Populating rest of the column values for each of value of one column in a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with some columns.

| ID | string | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | zero | abc |
| 1 | one | def |
| 2 | two | ghi |
| 3 | three | jkl |
| 4 | four | mno |

I want to populate rest of the columns for each ID value

| ID | string | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | zero | abc |
| 0 | one | def |
| 0 | two | ghi |
| 0 | three | jkl |
| 0 | four | mno |
| 1 | zero | abc |
| 1 | one | def |
| 1 | two | ghi |
| 1 | three | jkl |
| 1 | four | mno |
| 2 | zero | abc |
| 2 | one | def |
| 2 | two | ghi |
| 2 | three | jkl |
| 2 | four | mno |
| 3 | zero | abc |
| 3 | one | def |
| 3 | two | ghi |
| 3 | three | jkl |
| 3 | four | mno |
| 4 | zero | abc |
| 4 | one | def |
| 4 | two | ghi |
| 4 | three | jkl |
| 4 | four | mno |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cross join:

```
result = df.select('ID').crossJoin(df.select('string', 'test'))

result.show(99)
+---+------+----+
| ID|string|test|
+---+------+----+
|  0|  zero| abc|
|  1|  zero| abc|
|  2|  zero| abc|
|  3|  zero| abc|
|  4|  zero| abc|
|  0|   one| def|
|  1|   one| def|
|  2|   one| def|
|  3|   one| def|
|  4|   one| def|
|  0|   two| ghi|
|  1|   two| ghi|
|  2|   two| ghi|
|  3|   two| ghi|
|  4|   two| ghi|
|  0| three| jkl|
|  1| three| jkl|
|  2| three| jkl|
|  3| three| jkl|
|  4| three| jkl|
|  0|  four| mno|
|  1|  four| mno|
|  2|  four| mno|
|  3|  four| mno|
|  4|  four| mno|
+---+------+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a self cross join :

```
df1 = df.alias("a").crossJoin(df.alias("b")) \
    .select("a.ID", "b.string", "b.test")

df1.show()

#+---+------+----+
#| ID|string|test|
#+---+------+----+
#|  0|   one| def|
#|  0|   two| ghi|
#|  0| three| jkl|
#|  0|  four| mno|
#|  1|  zero| abc|
#|  1|   two| ghi|
#|  1| three| jkl|
#|  1|  four| mno|
#|  3|  zero| abc|
#|  3|   one| def|
#|  3|   two| ghi|
#|  3|  four| mno|
#|  2|  zero| abc|
#|  2|   one| def|
#|  2| three| jkl|
#|  2|  four| mno|
#|  4|  zero| abc|
#|  4|   one| def|
#|  4|   two| ghi|
#|  4| three| jkl|
#+---+------+----+
```

---

Another way is collecting `ID` values and using list comprehension, create dataframes with column `ID` as a literal value, and other values from columns `string` and `test`. Then using union to get the desired result

```
import functools
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [
    df.filter(F.col("ID") != r.ID).selectExpr(f"{r.ID} as ID", "string", "test")
    for r in df.select("ID").distinct().collect()
]

df1 = functools.reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs + [df])
```